# Adding namespace in version 2 of Savon

Tags: savon

What is the analogy of this Savon version 1 code in Savon version 2?

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.endpoint = "http://..."
  wsdl.namespace = "http://..." # target namespace
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 2 of Savon you need to use following syntax:

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl 'https://...'  
  namespace 'http://...'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the preferred way to execute those in Savon 2.x is

```
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: 'http://...'
    namespace: 'http://...',
    log: true,
    log_level: :debug,
    pretty_print_xml: true
)

rc = client.call(:soap_methods_name,
                 message: { :param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2' })
```