# SAVON setting envelope namespace in the envelope

Tags: savon

i'm trying to add a namespace in my envelop for xmlns:api= and set the url as example:

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="http://api.notes.xyz.com/">`

not having much success in finding examples.
Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to look at my answer from 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684820/adding-namespace-in-version-2-of-savon/19692629

Comment: @SteffenRoller thanks for that point-out. I am trying to specifically to create xmlns:api = "http://api.endpoint"   I don't see how to do that.. in your example the wsdl.namespace in the client sets xmlns:wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done in the past was the following (I always preferred to go without WSDL). Perhaps you can use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'savon'

additional_ns = {
 'xmlns:api' => "http://api.notes.xyz.com/"
}

client = Savon.client(
    :endpoint => "http://www.example.com/endpoint",
    :namespace => "xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    :namespaces => additional_ns,
    :log => true,
    :log_level => :debug,
    :pretty_print_xml => true,
    :ssl_verify_mode => :none
)

client.call(....)
```